# Gmail / Inbox : have our website icon show instead of the circled letter

Tags: email, gmail, icons, favicon, inbox

I don't understand how some websites (LinkedIn, Youtube, Houzz, ...) have their favicon to show in Google Inbox. It is awesome! How come mine does not show? First I thought I had to put a favicon.ico in my public root folder... But I found out I already have.

So, what would allow me to have my favicon display instead of the colored circled letter in Gmail / Inbox (or other apps) ?

[image]

Thank you all!

Answer (score 3):

Create a google account with your company mail address xyz@xyz.com and then upload a logo to the profile.
Then send some bulk email more than 200 using script, then your logo will start appear in the mail favicon.

Try 200 to 1000 bcoz i dont know the exact count and the algorithm which google used to show-up

create google account without gmail: https://accounts.google.com/SignUpWithoutGmail?hl=en

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: inbox by google doesn't exist anymore :( and the gmail app don't use favicons so the below isn't true anymore.

If you haven't figured it out by now, here's a late answer :)
There's a couple of different kind of "favicons" you can specify and I assume gmail uses one of the other kinds of favicons.
This article has a good explanation https://css-tricks.com/favicon-quiz/ and it recommends that you use this service http://realfavicongenerator.net/ to generate code for adding these other kind of favicions to your site.